# How use Mongoose on inner npm module

Tags: node.js, mongoose, npm

How can I use a **Mongoose** already opened connection inside an **npm** module that resides in `/node_modules`?

For instance:

- app

  - common

    - [db.js](http://pastebin.com/Z7nVgk9P)
  - node_modules

    - a_module

      - models

        - [a_model.js](http://pastebin.com/V0HimPtM)
      - [index.js](http://pastebin.com/H0f6qczX)
  - [app.js](http://pastebin.com/CGh1EacR)

`app.js` trigger opens a connection by `requir`ing `common/db.js` and executing a `connect()` method.

Later in `app.js` a call is made to `a_model/index.js` where is required the `a_model.js` file and then is issued a `findOne()` call that never gets executed since it detects that no connection is open so the call is enqueued forever and never executes.

I already checked that the connection is already opened by checking the logs so the issue is other.

It's worth to note that I was able to get a similar setup working fine but instead of having `a_module` to be a `npm` module it was a regular directory below the `app` folder.

**SOLUTION**

Finally I got this working properly with the help of the awesome guys below.

By using the `global` nodejs object I was able to expose the db connection without clutter the code:

**db.js:**

```
global.db = mongoose;
```

**a_model.js:**

```
mongoose = global.db;
```

and voilá!

Reference: http://productbuilder.wordpress.com/2013/09/06/using-a-single-global-db-connection-in-node-js/

Comment: Does `a_module` have its own `node_modules` folder which contains its own instance of `mongoose`?

Comment: @jibsales: Yes, indeed. Could that be the origin of the issue?

Comment: Yup! See my answer below.

Comment: Would this still be the way in 2017?

Comment: @MatthiasMax No idea, I moved later to `Sequelize` instead of `Mongoose`. Give it a try and post an update comment here if you are up to :)

Comment: isn't this what peer dependencies is for - in your example, the a_module should specify mongoose in its package.json in peerDependencies ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Node caches calls to `require` so that you don't have to reinit the module on each `require`.

http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_caching

However, sub dependencies are not guaranteed to use the same object:

http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_module_caching_caveats

`mongoose` connections depend on this caching mechanism to keep an open connection to MongoDB. So in your case, when you moved `a_module` into its own module, you're essentially instantiating two `mognoose` objects and only your first `mongoose` object is opening a connection. The second object never opens a connection.

You can fix this by either having each module establish their own connection, or you'll have to go back to `a_module` not being an independent package.

Comment: WIth this piece of informacion I could keep in track and solve the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

option 1:

```
// app.js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = require('db')(mongoose);
var a_module = require('a_module')(mongoose);
```

option 2:

```
re-check package.json for each modules. Make sure they are resolvable to a single version of mongoose.

BAD DEPENDENCIES:
app.js need  {"mongoose": "3.8"}
a_module need {"mongoose": "3.7"}
=> npm install will download 2 separated version of mongoose. 

GOOD DEPENDENCIES:
app.js need {"mongoose": ">= 3.8"}
a_module need {"mongoose": ">= 3.7"}
=> npm install will download 1 mongoose version for all app and a_module
```

Comment: I checked option 2 and the mongoose version is shared among app.js and the inner module, and the issue is still there.

Comment: remove directory app/node_modules/a_module/node_modules, then call npm install again. It should be 1 version and 1 folder of mongoose.

Comment: Yes, it is only a single mongoose module across the entire app but it still doesn't work.

I think option 1 would be a solution but I don't like to pass it to inner callbacks the mongoose object, since can get very nasty when app has several nested levels (like mine, that have 3).

Comment: oh, i didn't know that, thank diosney. I must read document now.

Comment: This does not the answer the question of passing around the connection.... in other words the instance of mongoose.